# Should a message queue be instantiated in the child process or the parent process?

Tags: python-3.x, process, message-queue, python-multiprocessing

Right now when I spawn a child process, I instantiate a message queue in the parent process, and pass it to the child in the constructor arguments, like so:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class testProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, msgQueue):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, daemon=True)
        self.msgQueue = msgQueue    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Instantiate queue in parent process and pass to child:
    msgQueue = mp.Queue()
    t = testProcess(msgQueue)
```

I do this because all the examples I saw when I was learning how to use multiprocessing did it this way.

However, I've got a lot of child processes now, and it's getting kind of ugly to spawn a bunch of queues in the parent process and keep track of them. It would be cleaner to spawn the queue within the `__init__` method of the child process, and simply access it in the parent as part of the child's namespace, like so:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class testProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, daemon=True)
        # Instantiate queue from within child __init__:
        self.msgQueue = mp.Queue()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = testProcess()
    # Now I can access the queue like so:
    t.msgQueue.put("hi there child")
```

I guess technically the `__init__` statement of the Process class is executed in the parent process anyways (I think?), so I don't think it can make any difference.

So, my question is, am I going to get hit with some kind of problem later on if I instantiate queues within the child process `__init__` statement? Is there any advantage of either way? Or are they equivalent?

Comment: @Darkonaut Yes, thanks for pointing that out - I've just removed the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference because like you already wrote, `Process.__init__()` is executed in the parent.

This means the question title:

> "Should a message queue be instantiated in the child process or the parent process?"

is wrong, because it happens in the parent process either way.

It's just a matter of code organization and for per-process connections your second code snippet makes much sense.

In case you really need one connection per Process, you can switch to [`multiprocessing.Pipe`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe) for some performance improvement. The regular `multiprocessing.Queue` spawns a feeder-thread on the first `.put()` and you don't need that for single-producer/single-consumer (SPSC) connections.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I thought, but I'm paranoid about multiprocessing, so I'm happy to get confirmation. It seems like there are more subtle pitfalls when using multiprocessing than single-process programming.

Comment: @Brionius Definitly, better safe than sorry for concurrency stuff ;)